# Peculiar performance of OpenMP code with tasks: 1 thread performing better than multiple threads

Tags: c, parallel-processing, task, openmp

I have the following code for which I have implemented a explicit tasking version :

```
int waves = N_a + N_b +1;  /*considering N_a == N_b */
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(a, gap, waves) private(temp, wave, ii, i) shared(np, mp, elements)
    {
#pragma omp master
        {
            for(wave = 0; wave < waves; ++wave) {
                // 0 <= wave < n-1
                if(wave < N_a-1) {
                    elements = wave+1;
                    np = wave+1;
                    mp = 0+1;
                }
                // n-1 <= wave < m
                else if(wave < N_b) {
                    elements = N_a;
                    np = N_a-1+1;
                    mp = wave-(N_a-1)+1;
                }
                // m <= wave < m+n-1
                else {
                    elements = N_a-1-(wave-N_b);
                    np = N_a-1+1;
                    mp = wave-(N_a-1)+1;
                }

                for(ii = 0; ii < elements; ii+=chunk) {
                    min = MIN(elements,ii + chunk);
#pragma omp task firstprivate(ii, np, mp, chunk, elements)
                    {
                        for (i = ii; i < min; i++)
                        {

                        temp[0] = H[(np-i)-1][(mp+i)-1] + similarity(seq_a[a][(np-i)-1],seq_b[a][(mp+i)-1]);
                        temp[1] = H[(np-i)-1][(mp+i)]-gap;
                        temp[2] = H[(np-i)][(mp+i)-1]-gap;
                        temp[3] = 0;
                        H[(np-i)][(mp+i)] = find_array_max(temp,4);
                        }
                    } // task
                } //for loop
 #pragma omp taskwait
            }
        }

    }
```

Strangely on executing the code the performance for 1 thread is much better that of 2, 4, 8 and 16 threads. There is only a single a parallel region and I have strip-mined the inner for loop so that every "chunk" number of elements will contribute to creating a task.

I insist on creating a task implementation, because the value of elements in this will constantly vary and I feel the code has potential to counter unstructured parallelism with an efficient tasking implementation.

I am trying this on the Intel xe12 version compiler. Following are the readings I am observing for sample chunk size: 256 and N_a = N_b = 4096:

1 threads: 1.237560 
2 threads: 7.223232 
4 threads: 4.579173 
8 threads: 3.663661 
16 threads:4.425525

I am noticing a similar behavior for gcc compiler a well. Can someone please why code with 1 thread is doing better than multiple threads.
I see similar results for N_a = N_b = 1024, 2048 and 8192 as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a small, self-contained example to play with?

Comment: You should check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320754/why-is-it-that-restricting-multithreaded-applications-to-one-core-make-it-run-fa/12461163#12461163) for understanding the performance.

Comment: "1 threads" means running with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` or compiling without OpenMP being enabled?

Answer (score 2):

All of your code is guarded by `#pragma omp master` which allows only the master thread to run all of the calculations. You must remove this pragma (or is there any reason for it?) to see at least some scaling.